# CFCHART - How do I get the Y-Axis to start at 1 instead of 0

Tags: coldfusion, cfchart

Here is the example style I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<frameChart is3D="false">
      <frame xDepth="3" yDepth="1" leftAxisPlacement="Back" isHStripVisible="true">
           <background minColor="#FDFEF6"/>
      </frame>
      <yAxis scaleMin="1" scaleMax="500">
           <labelFormat pattern="#,##0.###"/>
           <parseFormat pattern="#,##0.###"/>
      </yAxis>
      <legend>
           <decoration style="None"/>
      </legend>
      <elements place="Default" shape="Line" drawShadow="true">
           <morph morph="Grow"/>
      </elements>
</frameChart>
```

The above code will show 0 instead of 1.

This seems to be a common problem using cfchart, but it appears to be a problem in the web charts program as well.

Does anyone have a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** It is possible, but there are some side effects in your specific case.

**Longer answer:**
You can force the y-axis to start at 1 by specifying the number of `labels` (ie grid lines). But as long the range is an odd number (`ie 500 - 1 ==> 499`) some of the y-axis values may not line up evenly.

```
<!--- labelCount is number of grid lines + 1 --->
<yAxis scaleMin="1" scaleMax="500" labelCount="6">
    <labelFormat style="Integer" pattern="#,##0"/>
</yAxis>
```

That is because y-axis values are calculated by dividing the `scale range` by the number of grid lines. With odd ranges that typically produces fractional numbers. For example, if you generated five (5) grid lines, the axis values would be:

```
Actual   => Rounded Value
500.0    => 500
400.2    => 400
300.4    => 300
200.6    => 201  **
100.8    => 101  **
  1.0    => 1
```

The only way to have *complete* control over all y-axis values is to ensure the range / grid lines works out to a whole number.